# Probabalistic-line fit function?

Tags: python, probability, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I fit the data (blue dots) to the function green-line

```
 fun = np.polyfit(x,y,3)
```

then I can calculate it :

```
 fun(0.5)
 : 2.118
```

Is there a way to fit a probabilistic function so that it returns values around the value-of-the fit line with appropriate probability of the fitting dataset.

I.e. is there a such thing as probabalistic-line-range fitting ? 
[image]

Comment: From the plot the data appears to have integer-only values for the dependent variable (y), however there seems to be a single data point with a y value of zero. With multiple data points at the other values of y, this will effectively weight any regression away from the zero point. If possible, I suggest making the number of data points at each y value to be  the same.

Comment: when i think about it may be I should fit probability distribution for every Y !! does numpy have prob-fit ?

Comment: This question is more conceptual so it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead of SO. What are the possible values of Y? Is Y really limited to integer values or is that a result of being able to measure it only to the nearest integer? What do these data represent, and what do you want to do with the fitted model? My advice is to take up this question on stats.stackexchange.com, stating that information.